# Sklearn Pipeline and column transformer increases number of Coefficients

Tags: python, pipeline, scaling, data-preprocessing

I want to first transform a set of columns using yeo-johnson and then transform the "newly transformed set of columns" using a standard scaler. Moreover, some more columns should be just standard scaled.

I have noticed that the current design returns more coefficients than there are columns; to be more precise: there are n more coefficients as there are in the "count_cols" (see below). Below you can find the pipeline i am referencing:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(
[
    ("preprocessor", ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ("count_transformer" , PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson'), count_cols),
            ("count_scaler", StandardScaler(), count_cols),
            ("qty_scaler", StandardScaler(), qty_cols + qty_other_cols)
        ], 
        remainder="passthrough"
    )),
    (
        "lr",
        LogisticRegression(
            class_weight=class_weight5,
            solver='saga',
              multi_class='multinomial',
              verbose=1,
              n_jobs = 7,
              max_iter=100,

        ),
    ),
]
```

)

As such, I have made some adjustments to the pipeline (see below) and now the right number of columns is returned, but I am not sure whether this is correct.

```
pipeline = Pipeline(
[
    ("preprocessor", ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ("count_transformer" , Pipeline([
                ('count_transform', PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson')),
                ('count_scaler', StandardScaler())
            ]), count_cols),
            ("qty_scaler", StandardScaler(), qty_cols + qty_other_cols)
        ],
        remainder="passthrough"
    )),
    (
        "lr",
        LogisticRegression(
            class_weight=class_weight5,
            solver='saga',
            multi_class='multinomial',
            verbose=1,
            n_jobs = 7,
            max_iter=100,

        ),
    ),
]
```

)

Could someone explain to me why the first pipeline returns more coefficients (using "pipeline.named_steps["lr"].coef_[0]") and,thus, does not properly work this way? Moreover, for some reason, the performance of the first pipeline (the supposedly wrong one) is considerably better than that of the second pipeline in addition to a hand full of coefficients being quite strong compared to most others (this might be due to multicollinearity introduced but using CV I see a persistently better performance still). What can be the reason for this?